# OData v4 EDM model - separate configuration classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'd like to use OData 4 along with WebApi2 and EF, where as for the latter I got about 30 model configuration classes. Now, since OData requires an EDM model, I would like to somehow reuse my existing model configuration - or at least put the configuration classes into a different library to keep my web api configuration manageable.

I tried creating EDM entity type configuration classes using `EntitySetConfiguration<'1>`, however the constructor of that class is internal. So - is there a way to automatically build an EDM model using a `DbContext` during runtime or create separate configuration classes?

Answer (score 2):

You can build an edm model using a DBContext via reflection.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    modelBuilder.ContainerName = "EntityContainer";

    using(var ctx = new MyDBContext()) 
    {
        var dbSets = ctx.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach(var set in dbSets)
        {
            if(set.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
            {
                 method = entitySet.MakeGenericMethod(set.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0]);
                 bool containsEntity = false;
                 foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.EntitySets)
                 {
                     if (entity.GetType().Equals(set.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0]))
                         containsEntity = true;


                     if (!containsEntity)
                         method.Invoke(modelBuilder, new[] { set.Name });
                  } 
             }
         }
     }
     _config.MapODataServiceRoute(
           routeName: "entities",
           routePrefix: API_ENTITIES_BASE_URI,
           model: modelBuilder.GetEdmModel()
           );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is the type of  entitySet ?